# Django Can't save form data on database

Tags: django

I'm trying write a small app while I'm learning django.However, when I try to save the form data in database, some problems happen to me.I use python3.4 and django 1.8.4, my database is MySql

The first problem I met is that the database doesn't have any data

this is my model code:

```
SUBJECT_CHOICES = (
('computerscience', '计算机科学导论'),
('C-sharp', 'C#'),
('cplusplus', 'C++'),
('CCNA', 'CCNA'),
('ACM', 'ACM'),
('linux', 'linux'),
('java', 'java'),
('python', 'python')
)

class Homework(models.Model):
    handin_date = models.DateTimeField('交作业时间')
    subject = models.CharField(verbose_name = '课程', default = '计算机科学导论', max_length = 20, choices = SUBJECT_CHOICES)
    code = models.TextField(verbose_name = '代码', default = '')
    xuehao = models.CharField(verbose_name = '学号', default = '', max_length = 9)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name = '姓名', default = '', max_length = 10)
```

this is my view code:

```
def cshomework(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'blog/success.html', { 'title': '交作业成功' })
    else:
        form = HomeworkForm(initial = { 'xuehao': '学号', 'name': '姓名', 'subject': '计算机科学导论', 'handin_date': dt.now(), 'code': '你的代码' })

    return render(request, 'blog/cshomework.html', { 'title': '交作业', 'form': form })
```

In this way there's nothing in my database

The seconde question is when I tried another way, I get a None value in my datebase

The same model code as before

Here is my view code:

```
def cshomework(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'blog/success.html', { 'title': '交作业成功' })
    else:
        homework = Homework.objects.create(xuehao = '学号', name = '姓名', subject = '计算机科学导论', handin_date = dt.now(), code = '你的代码')
        form = HomeworkForm(instance = homework)        

    return render(request, 'blog/cshomework.html', { 'title': '交作业', 'form': form })
```

[the '课程' means 'subject'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcA9w.png)

How can I deal with these problems?
I' really appriciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all check if form.is_valid(), you need save the form.

```
 def cshomework(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = HomeworkForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return render(request, 'blog/success.html', { 'title': '交作业成功' })
         else:
             form = HomeworkForm(initial = { 'xuehao': '学号', 'name': '姓名', 'subject': '计算机科学导论', 'handin_date': dt.now(), 'code': '你的代码' })

        return render(request, 'blog/cshomework.html', { 'title': '交作业', 'form': form })
```

At the second way, you are creating a new HomeWork everytime a URL is accessed, without submit any post data.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It sovles my problem. But why the seconde method can save some data?

Comment: you have add the form.save() too ?

Comment: everytime you GET the url, an object is created, is correct? you want create a new HomeWork, everytime someone access the URL, without submit any data?

Comment: I'm so sorry that it seems I have't earn up to 15 reputation, so I can't change the publicly displayed post score. I have marked it as the answer. Maybe I should try to answer some questions first.

Comment: Oh, thats ok, thank you to mark as the answer, when you get 15+ rep, you can come back and upvote if wants. :)

Comment: Yes, I will. You really sovle my promble. You deserve it.

Comment: For more knowledge, if you're not using a ModelForm you can create a variable like this: b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.') and then call b2.save() to save an object in the database. Taken from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/